# Register a user without Mail

Tags: user-registration, twiki

I have no mail activated and the var {EnableMail} in configure is unchecked. I have the following issue. When i want to register a new user, i fill out the form and click on submit.

After that, the browser makes an redirect to the logon window with the following url "http://myservername/twiki/bin/login/Main/TWikiRegistration?twiki_redirect_cache=15a9c3ed0ae9a5d2bef4e9bd3f72b008"

In this form, i typing in the logon credentials as typed in into the form and receive an error message ""You're already registered". But the user exist in the system. if i type in the url manually and logon the user, all works fine.

For my opinion, this is a wron behavior. Either the browser is redirected after registration with an logged on user to the homepage or the browser is redirected to the logon screen for typing in the crdentials and logging on a user.

Please help me, i'm not able to register any user with an intuitive behavior.

Twiki 5.1.0
Ubuntu 11.10
Oerl 5.12.4

Also asked on [Twiki Support Site](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Support/SID-01312)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was planning to restict the access to the main web for "normal registered untrusted users". For this purpose, i set the var ALLOWWEBCHANGES = TrustedGroup in main web preferences.
This caused the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. I'd expect that the TWiki support forum should have a workaround tho

(thats certainly not the state we left the code when the community forked to foswiki)

Comment: Hi Sven, thank you for your answer. This is not a bug but some issue with the right management as you can see in my answer below. Normally i didn't answer my oqn questions. But maybe others running in the same problems, so i want to present a solution. Thank you anyway